# Same macro working in one excel spreadsheet but not another (used to work)

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to hide blank rows in two different tables in the same tab. The issue is that the first macro mentioned below works in the second tab (called SERVICES) but doesn't work in the third tab (called THIRD-PARTY). Both macros in each tab are assigned to buttons (one on each tab). On top of that, the same macro (the first one mentioned below - the longer one without the loop) used to work in this tab but stopped all of a sudden for some reason so I really need to know why it stopped working to prevent it from happening in the future as well as find out how to fix either of the macros mentioned below.

```
Sub HideRowsInThirdPartyTabTemp()
Call TurnOffFunctions
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Rows("8:23") = " " Then
    Range("8:23").Rows.Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B36") = 0 Then
      Range("29:48").Rows.Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B57") = 0 Then
      Range("50:69").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B78") = 0 Then
      Range("71:90").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B99") = 0 Then
      Range("92:111").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B120") = 0 Then
      Range("113:132").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B141") = 0 Then
      Range("134:153").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B162") = 0 Then
      Range("155:174").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B183") = 0 Then
      Range("176:195").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B204") = 0 Then
      Range("197:216").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B225") = 0 Then
      Range("218:237").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B246") = 0 Then
      Range("239:258").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B267") = 0 Then
      Range("260:279").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B288") = 0 Then
      Range("281:300").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B309") = 0 Then
      Range("302:321").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B330") = 0 Then
      Range("323:342").Hidden = True
End If
If Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B351") = 0 Then
      Range("344:363").Hidden = True
End If
Call TurnOnFunctions
End Sub
```

The macro above is the one that had been working and is still working in a different tab. I also tried the macro below since I am trying to use loop more. However, this macro had its own issues. It only hides blank rows in the second table (in the THIRD-PARTY tab), not the first table (in the THIRD-PARTY tab). Granted I am new to using VBA but can't understand why it would work in one part of the workbook but not the other. At first I thought the B8:B23 (rows to be hidden if blank in the first table in the THIRD-PARTY tab) wasn't working because these cells are merged but I had the same problem when I un-merged them. Not sure if it affects it but the cells in the first table (in the THIRD-PARTY tab) do reference cells from the second table (also in the THIRD-PARTY tab, each cell in B8:B23 sums each corresponding section in the second table.

```
Sub HideRowsInThirdPartyTabDim()
Call TurnOffFunctions
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("B8:B23,C37:C56,C58:C77,C79:C98,C100:C119,C121:C140,C142:C161,C163:C182,C184:C203,C205:C224,C226:C245, C247:C266,C268:C287,C289:C308,C310:C329,C331:C350,C352:C371")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call TurnOnFunctions
End Sub
```

Comment: Anytime you use range() VBA assumes that your are referencing the ActiveSheet.   You should qualify all your Range statements. Just like you did with Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("B36")

Comment: Your unqualified `Range("num:num").Hidden = True` **always** implicitly works on `ActiveSheet`. Wrap all the `If` statements in a `With Sheets("Third-Party")` then make all the calls `.Range()` NOTE the leading `.` - this will make them all reference the `Third-Party` worksheet

Comment: Also, please only post 1 question per post. Feel free to [edit] your post to remove the second question and post a whole new one. It's really hard to answer two questions in one in the StackExchange format.

Comment: Sorry about that, @FreeMan. I only included the second macro (the loop macro) to show all the different ways I have tried to solve this issue. Someone could solve the second if easier instead of tackling the longer first one but I'm not asking someone to solve both macros.

Comment: Thanks, @mooseman. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: @mooseman. Sorry I didn't mention in my summary but this macro is assigned to a macro button which is located in the THIRD-PARTY tab so shouldn't the THIRD-PARTY tab be the ActiveSheet and therefore work?

Comment: True, it might be, but it is good VBA programming to not assume so.  It is not much to put Sheets("THIRD-PARTY"). before the range you need to be on THIRD-PARTY sheet

Comment: BTW - Why in the longer macro do you have the cells = to 0 or blank, but in the shorter one you have the length of the cell value being = to 0.   These are totally different comparisons.  A cell that is = 0 has a length of 1

Comment: Oh ok, thanks @mooseman. I didn't mean to put length, thanks for catching that. I want to have the value = 0, not the length. What should I put instead of Len?

Comment: If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then  changes to If c.value = 0 Then

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner but I really appreciate it, mooseman!

Answer (score 0):

Your unqualified `Range("num:num").Hidden = True` always implicitly works on ActiveSheet.

Wrap all the code in a `With` statement like this and it should work just fine

```
Sub HideRowsInThirdPartyTabTemp()
  TurnOffFunctions
  With Sheets("THIRD-PARTY")
  If .Rows("8:23") = " " Then
    .Range("8:23").Rows.Hidden = True
  End If
  If .Range("B36").Value = 0 Then
    .Range("29:48").Rows.Hidden = True
  End If
  If .Range("B57").Value = 0 Then
    .Range("50:69").Hidden = True
  End If
  'etc
  End With
End Sub
```

Note that there is a `.` before the `Range()` method calls, that tells the compiler that this belongs to whatever you're doing it `With`.

Note: consistent indenting is *really* helpful in reading your code.

Note 2: There is no need for `Call` - it's been deprecated for years and is only still supported so people running *ancient* code that hasn't yet been edited don't have to edit it out to run it in newer versions of VBA.

Note 3: I added `.Value` to the end of the `.Range()` statements to make it explicitly clear what you're looking at. `.Value` is the default property for `.Range()` when used that way, but it's always best to say what you mean and mean what you say.

Comment: Hey @FreeMan. Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it but I got an error message when I tried running your macro. I'm getting the type mismatch error message, specifically highlighting the line ```  If .Rows("8:23") = " " Then``` I tried replacing the Rows with Range but Excel gave me the same run time error. I don't know if it affects things like this but I am working on a Macbook Air.

Comment: I also tried replacing " " with 0 but am still getting the run time error (13): mismatch. The sheet is protected but in a macro located in ThisWorksheet which is written specifically to also avoid hindering other macros.

Comment: @CTEAGUE212 That `.Rows("8:23")` is a verbatim copy of what you originally posted, so I'd think that your original code wouldn't work correctly either. It probably needs to be `.Range("8:23").Rows`. **BUT**, I'm not sure what, exactly, that's going to give you back. All the rest are looking at `.Range(a single cell)`, while this one is looking at a range. You may want to check to see if that's a typo, maybe it should be `.Range("B23")` since all the rest are looking at cells in column `B`?